# How to fix stretched splash image in Unity?

Tags: unity

I'm trying to add my own splash on my Unity project. However, when I implement it, the splash is stretched vertically, real bad.

Here is the screenshot:
[image: My own splash in the build. How to fix this?]

While the original splash is:
[image: How it should appeared :(]

I'm not altering the settings for the sprite that much:
[image: The settings for the sprite. No major changes.]

How to fix that problem? I'm using a 1080x1080 PNG file for the splash and Unity 5.5.0f for building the application. Altering the resolution of the PNG results no luck. Am I missing something important here?

EDIT: Sorry for the late mention, but I've made the border on the sprite editor. Still no luck.
[image: This doesn't change anything. Still stretched like hell.]

Comment: This is most likely a problem with the sprite editor. Try going in there and changing the borders of the sprite. If not, it has to be the splash image settings under player settings.

Comment: @JohnHamilton I've edited the question to include my sprite editor configurations. Still no luck. :(

Comment: Also, I don't found any sign to fix this problem on the Player Settings :/

Comment: Check this : Check this: Splash Image/Splash Screen tutorial | WFG #002
https://youtu.be/YTpfrrXetNw

Comment: Well, didn't expect this to be necrocommented. I have since moved on to Unreal Engine anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright. So I just stumbled across the Import Settings, and found that the solution to this problem is just by setting the *Mesh Type* into **Full Rect**, nothing to do with the Sprite Editor. Newbies can miss this, because by default, Unity set the *Mesh Type* into **Tight** instead.

Actually, my bad I didn't experimenting with the Import Settings last time, so I apologize for this. But I guess it's a bit worth mentioning anyways.